# Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present, with gradle springfox-swagger2: 3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, springfox, swagger-3.0

I'm trying to Implement swagger in my spring boot project. I searched on internet and found that springfox 3.0 might not compatible with spring boot 3.0. I tried with the older versions as well. But I'm not able to do that.
I'm using **gradle**.

**ERROR IN TERMINAL**

[image]

**Build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'practice.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '19'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**main java file**

```
package practice.example.crud_practice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@RestController
public class CrudPracticeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudPracticeApplication.class, args);
    }



    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()) // this will include all controllers
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
      }

      @GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
}
}
```

**WHEN I COMEMNT THE FOLLOWING LINE OUT TERMINAL SHOWS NO ERROR**

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems Springfox 3 is not compatible with Spring Boot 3.

**Reason**:

- [As you can see](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/3.0.0/springfox-spring-integration-webmvc/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/SpringIntegrationWebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java) Springfox 3 references `HttpServletRequest` from the package `javax.servlet.http`.
- Spring Boot 3 bundles the new `jakarta.servlet.http` package via its `tomcat-embed-core` dependency.

**Solution**: Use Spring Boot 2.x

If you want to use Springfox 3, you should probably stick to Spring Boot 2.x to have a working system.

**Alternative**: Migrate to `springdoc-openapi`

You may also use [springdoc-openapi v2](https://springdoc.org/v2/) instead, which supports Spring Boot 3. I have followed [the migration guide](https://springdoc.org/v2/#migrating-from-springfox) for your scenario and it worked fine (URL is `localhost:8080/v3/api-docs`).

- Removed springfox dependency
- Added `implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'` dependency
- Removed the `Docket` bean and springfox imports
- Added `springdoc.pathsToMatch=/**` to `application.properties`

Comment: OK Solved it. Thanks A lot for your time and effort!

Comment: For those coming late here: I recommend that you go for the springdoc-openapi alternative. Springfox is no longer maintained, and eventually you will want/need to move to Spring Boot 3 anyway I guess.